# How get the multirow tabbar support in Komodo Edit environment?

Tags: komodo, komodoedit, multirow, tabbed-browsing

In light of always having many, many, Komodo Edit tabs open, I would appreciate a solution to adjust the tabbar layout to support multirow tabs.

Is there any add-on which adds multirow tabs support to Komodo Edit environment (something like the TooManyTabs add-on for Firefox)?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [tweak-ui](http://community.activestate.com/xpi/tweak-ui) and [tabtools](http://community.activestate.com/xpi/tabtools) extensions for this functionality. One adds an option to Edit=>Preferences=>Appearance=>Tabs. The other adds context menu options for tabs.